# How make children of absolutely positioned element disappear, when we set its height to zero?

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I have div with class of 'box' inside my body. And that div contains another div with a class of 'box-inside'. I have set the absolute position on 'box' and set all inset properties to zero to make it span whole width of body. Now, I have set its height to zero but the box inside it does not disappear, it's still at its place. How to make inside box disappear with zero height?

```
.box {

  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.box .box-inside {
  padding: 2em;
  background: #f4f4;
}
```

Change the height of '.box' to get a clear idea.
Here is a link on Codepen: https://codepen.io/aqib-ali-01/pen/ZEyEWKE?editors=0100

Comment: overflow:hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CSS property `overflow`. This property is placed on a container element (in your case the div with a class of `box`) and it controls the behavior of the content that is too big to fit in the container.

To hide all the content that overflows a parent use `overflow: hidden`. Your CSS will look like the following.

```
.box {

  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.box .box-inside {
  padding: 2em;
  background: #f4f4;
}
```

Comment: Thank You! Mate! I had a lot of trouble getting around it but, didn't know solution was so simple.